# How to get empty result set instead of waiting transaction end in SQL Server Service Broker RECEIVE?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I want to use multiple clients processing messages in service broker queue. Their code would be looking like this:

```
select from queue
get @h = conversation_handle of message to process
begin transaction
receive message from queue where conversation_handle = @h
process message
commit transaction
```

(By not committing until message is successfully processed, I ensure, that if process dies then the message it has received but not yet processed won't get dropped from the queue.)

The problem is when several clients simultaneously try to receive the same message. First client receive and begin to process message (takes much time) and other clients wait the end of the receive query because of lock. I want clients to receive empty row set in case of locks instead of waiting the end of transaction. I tried WAITFOR (RECEIVE), TIMEOUT, but it didn't fit, still infinitely waiting the end of transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
receive message from queue where conversation_handle = @h
```

By adding a WHERE clause you are forcing the block. What you're trying to do is an anti-pattern: having multiple clients wait share a queue, but each client being interested only in own messages. Is not going to work, trust me, I've seen many people trying and I'm yet to see anyone succeed.

If you must have each client receive only its own messages then each client must use a separate queue (which implies separate services). The problems of deploying a queue/service per client are trivial compared to the problem of partitioning one queue for many clients (like you're trying now).

Comment: But each client should receive messages of the same type. Something like queue of orders that could be processed by any free client.

Comment: If any message can be processed by any client, then why do you add a WHERE clause? Just let the clients get the next available message, any message.

Comment: If you have messages that are not logically connected then you shouldn't structure things such that they get the same conversation handle.